# Turn on Network discovery in windows xp

Tags: networking, windows-xp

I am having difficulty turning on network discovery on Windows XP; Currently our server is not shown in the 'Network' section of a client computer, but I can ping the server. My system admin said I should turn on network discovery on the server.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to look at "File and Printer Sharing" options through Windows Explorer and enable NetBIOS/"Client for Windows Networking" through "Network Connections" in Control Panel...

Answer (score 3):

*TO TURN ON NETWORK DISCOVERY IN WINDOWS XP*

1. From the Start Menu, click Control Panel.
2. Click Network Connections.
3. Right Click "Local Area Connection", choose and click Properties.
4. Make sure that "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" is marked check.
5. Double click Internet Protocol (TCP/IP).
6. Click Advanced.
7. Click WINS.
8. Click the Enable NetBIOS Over TCP/IP button.